# Analytics super proxys using lots of datastore write operations

Tags: google-app-engine, analytics

I have setup analytics superproxy to display some realtime analytics information on a dashboard. Right now I have 4 queries I created that are on a schedule to update ever 30 seconds. I display the information using the link generated in the analytics superproxy. The problem is I am using my datastore write operations in a rediculously fast amount of time...I have used my free quote up in a matter of a few hours. I do not understand what is causing this.

Looking at the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing

a GET operation only uses 1 write, and the API calls are GET's..where is the datastore writes coming in and why is it using it up so fast?
Thanks in advance for any help

As a side note...this seems to continue to go up even after shutting down the analytics superproxy? Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after studying the code I detected some points that could be improved to avoid it.

The problem is at the crontask, it use 1 read and 2 writes. You can convert it to 1 read and 1 write adding a condition to one of the writes.

Another problem is the process to disable queries if they are not used. You can remove it if you know that you will use them periodically (which is my case).

You can see all this changes at a this fork: https://github.com/nmaletm/google-analytics-super-proxy